# What if our eyes can detect all EM waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, vision

What if our eyes can detect all EM waves (UV, radio, IR, gamma) along with the visible light. How will our vision looks like then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a hypothetical *What if X happened* that is [explicitly off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on this site.

Comment: I didn't know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could get above the earth's atmosphere to "look" into space with all-vision eyes, you could look towards the center of a galaxy and see the violent x-rays surrounding its central black hole.

You could look out at the plane of our own galaxy and see the infrared radiation coming through the dust clouds in the spiral arms.

You could look off into the distance beyond the furthest galaxies and see the cool, dim glow of the cosmic microwave background- a relic of the Big Bang.

With the right telescope, you could see the relativistic jets shooting out from a black hole millions of light years away, sending out huge mounts of power in the radio frequency band.

Oh, the things you could see! And how do we know those signals are out there? Because we have clever machines which can detect those signals and allow us to "see" them, even though our eyes cannot.

It would be a wonderful thing indeed- but alas, it cannot be done. See Rob Jeffries' comments below.

Comment: Perhaps you could discuss the issue of angular resolution. It seems to me you comments about radio emission are incorrect from this point of view. Equally, if our eyes are "sensitive" to X-rays, I'm struggling to see how they could be imaged. The central black hole in our Galaxy does not exhibit strong X-ray emission. Some indication of the relative flux of all these things is also needed isn't it? Our eyes are sensitive to visible light, but we can only see magnitude 6 stars and brighter.

Comment: And further. X-rays, UV and far infrared do not penetrate the Earth's atmosphere. Any near infrared radiation from astronomical sources would be drowned out by emission by the sky.

Comment: my answer assumed that telescopes of some sort might exist to address the angular resolution issue. I also assumed that magic human "eyes" could indeed image x-rays, even though you and I know that this is physiologically impossible. I'll correct the x-ray issue right now.

Comment: got it, also corrected the part regarding the atmosphere- thanks for pointing that out.